# Spring Validation : Server side systems

Tags: spring, spring-validator

The more I read the more I find that the MVC @Validate is mainly intended for web applications, including online samples for me to get my head around the actual use.

I have completely server side message processing project and we are looking to implement validation as cross cutting concern really, where we should be able to write validations / custom messages etc and apply to the methods as needed and reuse them.
Is spring Validation right choice ?

Does any one have samples or point me to right material ? Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at [Bean Validation](http://beanvalidation.org/). With the advent of JavaEE 7 in June 2013 it can be used in every Java project.

Comment: Thanks, the other concern that is mainly haunting me putting everything at bean level is having custom validations, I want to externalize the validations as far as possible from the code. The main reason is that the business entity beans are not polluted and I should have different validators for different purpose for same business object (bean) eg. quantity field of bean puts restriction < 0 in one case and <0 and > 100 in other case. I want it to use this validations per scenario dynamically.